# What is the solution to Error during conditional logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

```
set<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2)  
gender<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0)  
smoke<-c(1,1,0,0, 1,0)  
case_control<-c(1,0,0,1,0,0)

data<-data.frame(set, gender, smoke, case_control)  
data$gender<-factor(data$gender, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("female", "male"))  
data$smoke<-factor(data$smoke, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("no", "yes"))  
data$case_control<-factor(data$case_control, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("control", "case"))
```

In dataset named "data", I tried to do conditional logistic regression

```
library(survival)  
clogit(formula = data$case_control~data$gender+strata(data$set), data = data, method = "exact")**
```

Error was displayed as below.

> Error in coxph(formula = Surv(rep(1, 6L), data$case_control) ~ data$gender +  : 
>     an id statement is required for multi-state models

What could be the possible solution to this problem?

Comment: See this [post](https://www.biostars.org/p/413670/).

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this too. `clogit` uses `coxph` and `surv` under the hood and after looking at the [documentation for `surv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/Surv.html) it appears that the problem is that the event argument (`case_control` in this example) is a factor. When the event is a factor, surv assumes there are multiple endpoints (the multi-state models mentioned in the error), so it needs an `id` label for each row to know which outcomes to assign to which participants. If you change your outcome to a numeric variable with

```
clogit(formula = as.numeric(data$case_control) ~
data$gender+strata(data$set), data = data, method = "exact")
```

it works just fine.